# Creating Twitter APP of crytical time

Tags: twitter

I want to make a twitter APP that tweets at 12:00:00 and exactly at 12:00:00, reducing all delays to the minimum(trying to be faster than just scheduling the tweet in tweetdeck).

Any ideas for which language to use, which twitter API(streaming, REST...), suggestions of possible algorithms...?

Answer (score 0):

You just cannot anticipate the duration of your Http Request nor the time that Twitter will take to process it.

Usually a request is processed in less than second. So I would personally initiate the Http Request to start at 11:59:50 if your connection is good enough.

I am personally the developer of the Tweetinvi library which is developed in C# that will let you publish a tweet in a single line of code, but I don't think any library or algorithm will be able to anticipate the time for Twitter to process your request.

What you could potentially do is have some statistics. Store the DateTime just before you invoke the line of code to publish your tweet. When your tweet is published look at the DateTime of creation in the json. Compare the 2 DateTime.

Repeat the previous operation multiple times and perform some statistics to improve your chance to publish at the exact time.